# How to load css and js file in laravel correctly using version 5.2

Tags: css, laravel, public, jss

[image]i have just clone  project from live and running in my local environment but i am unable to load my files js and css all the stuff is crash.

Currently my css , js , fonts and images are under public folder and in view its like

```
       {!!Html::style('css/bootstrap.min.css')!!}
       {!!Html::style('css/font-awesome.min.css')!!}
       {!!Html::style('css/reset.css')!!}
       {!!Html::style('css/superslides.css')!!}
```

and images

```
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="{{asset('images/favicon/apple-icon-57x57.png')}}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="{{asset('images/favicon/apple-icon-60x60.png')}}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="{{asset('images/favicon/apple-icon-72x72.png')}}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="{{asset('images/favicon/apple-icon-76x76.png')}}">
```

is it right way to do that because on live its working fine but in local its not working i have also add package of collective html but not working
How to load these file correctly
Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using a link tag rather than using the Html facade? Something like this: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">

Comment: nop its not working

Comment: If your files are located properly, using the above code should work. There is something funny going on with your installation. When you say that "stuff is crash", what does that mean? Are you getting 404 errors on just your CSS and JS, or is the entire project not loading with some other error?

Comment: i have added a picture please see its on every page showing like this

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can load `JS` and `CSS` files the same ay you load your images using `asset` eg:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/font-awesome.min.css') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/reset.css') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/superslides.css') }}" />
```

In the examples above make sure your CSS files are located in the `app/public/css` folder, same applies for `JS` files

Comment: i have tried same but i dont know why its not working i am still confuse my css and js files are under public folder and applied with above example but same display

Comment: then consider reinstalling laravel, it usually should work

Answer (score 0):

You can load it using asset('/path to your file') or public_path('/path to your file').

Remember to add the forward slash '/' before the urls. e.g.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="{{asset('/images/favicon/apple-icon-57x57.png')}}">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="{{asset('/images/favicon/apple-icon-60x60.png')}}">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="{{asset('/images/favicon/apple-icon-72x72.png')}}">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="{{asset('/images/favicon/apple-icon-76x76.png')}}">
```